# Maintain Element in PHP Array And Update in PHP Class

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have one PHP class as below (part of the code):

```
class myclass{
    private static $arrX = array();

    private function is_val_exists($needle, $haystack) {
        if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach($haystack as $element) {
            if(is_array($element) && $this->is_val_exists($needle, $element))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //the $anInput is a string e.g. Michael,18

    public function doProcess($anInput){

        $det = explode(",", $anInput);

        if( $this->is_val_exists( $det[0], $this->returnProcess() ) ){
            //update age of Michael
        }
        else{
            array_push(self::$arrX, array(
                'name' => $det[0],
                'age'  => $det[1]
            ));
        }

    }

    public function returnProcess(){
        return self::$arrX;
    }
}
```

The calling code in `index.php`

```
$msg = 'Michael,18';
myclass::getHandle()->doProcess($msg);
```

In my webpage says `index.php`, it calls function `doProcess()` over and over again. When the function is called, string is passed and stored in an array. In the next call, if let's say same name is passed again, I want to update his age. My problem is I don't know how to check if the array `$arrX` contains the name.  From my own finding, the array seems to be re-initiated (back to zero element) when the code is called. My code never does the update and always go to the `array_push` part. Hope somebody can give some thoughts on this. Thank you.

Comment: to check if a key is in an array, check out the array_key_exists function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php  :)

Comment: can you share some data sample of `$arrX`!

Comment: show us the calling code

Comment: @flauntster I don't want to check the key, because the key will always same, I am actually checking the value whether it is exists or not

Comment: @jogesh_pi it is commented in the code part, e.g Michael,18 It is just two things delimited by comma

Comment: @niyou calling code included in question.

Comment: By "over and over again" do you mean in the same request or once per every request? Because the state isn't saved between requests in PHP therefore "the array seems to be re-initiated (back to zero element) ", you'd have to use a database instead.

Comment: @UserProg you should return the array key instead of true in `is_val_exists` method and false on failure.

Comment: @UserProg sorry i didnt read the question properly, i assumed the array was  [name] => [age] format, which would make it easier to find if a name is already in the array.

Comment: @asaddude once per every request. Oh I guess that is what I want. No other way to save the state of the array?

Comment: @jogesh_pi why do I need to return the key instead of true? the objective of the function is just to check whether the value exists or not, that's all

Comment: @flauntster I am having problem because the state of the array is not stored.

Comment: @UserProg afraid not, you should use some external storage e.g. MySQL or Redis

Comment: @asaddude really. if that is the case, maybe the external storage is required then.

Comment: @asaddude more clarification. Actually the calling code is executed multiple times (the page contains the calling code is called by AJAX). the page itself will be called repeatedly over and over :-)

Comment: @UserProg it's still separate requests, even if it's Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, it looks like you want to maintain state between requests. You can't use pure PHP to do that, you should use an external storage solution instead. If it's available, try [Redis](http://redis.io), it has what you need and is quite simple to use. Or, if you're familiar with SQL, you could go with MySQL for example.

On a side note, you should read more about how PHP arrays work.

1. Instead of array_push, you could have just used `self::$arrX[] = ...`
2. Instead of that, you could have used an associative array, e.g. `self::$arrX[$det[0]] = $det[1];`, that would make lookup much easier (`array_key_exists` etc.)

Comment: `Maintain state between request` Yup that is the key. If PHP is not possible, I will use MySQL then. I can maintain the state/value with `SESSION` but I don't want to because that might burden the memory.

Comment: @UserProg you can use `$_SESSION` yes, but as the name says, it's per-session storage, that is, there will be separate session (and data) for each user. If this is what you need, and not a global state, then go for it.

Comment: Understood but `$_SESSION` might not be my best option as the data is getting bigger and I don't want it kills the memory. MySQL is my best option. Thanks for your explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `)` missing in your else condition of your `doProcess()` function, it should read:

```
    else{
        array_push(self::$arrX, array(
            'name' => $det[0],
            'age'  => $det[1]
        ));  // <-- there was the missing )
    }
```

Here is a complete running solution based on your code:

```
<?php
 class myclass{
    private static $arrX = array();

    private function is_val_exists($needle, $haystack) {
        if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach($haystack as $element) {
            if(is_array($element) && $this->is_val_exists($needle, $element))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //the $anInput is a string e.g. Michael,18

    public function doProcess($anInput){

        $det = explode(",", $anInput);

        if( $this->is_val_exists( $det[0], $this->returnProcess() ) ){
            //update age of Michael
            for ($i=0; $i<count(self::$arrX); $i++) {
              if (is_array(self::$arrX[$i]) && self::$arrX[$i]['name'] == $det[0]) {
                self::$arrX[$i]['age'] = $det[1];
                break;
              }
            }
        } else{
            array_push(self::$arrX, array(
                'name' => $det[0],
                'age'  => $det[1]
            ));
        }

    }

    public function returnProcess(){
        return self::$arrX;
    }
}

$mc = new myclass();
$mc->doProcess('Michael,18');
$mc->doProcess('John,23');
$mc->doProcess('Michael,19');
$mc->doProcess('John,25');
print_r($mc->returnProcess());

?>
```

You can test it here: [PHP Runnable](http://runnable.com/VSOzGoBvBGUsCOLH/update-name-on-second-call-for-php)

Comment: thanks for the catch but the problem is still there.

Comment: @UserProg added a running sample based on your code now

Comment: page does not exists at php runnable

Comment: I already tested it and yes it worked but almost satisfy my requirement. The request is repeated and I want to maintain the value just like what `SESSION` does. So I believe PHP cannot do this, maybe MySQL is my best option. Thanks, appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating the is_val_exists as follows:

```
private function is_val_exists($needle, $haystack) {
foreach($haystack as $element) {
    if ($element['name'] == $needle) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The array is actually a multidimensional array so this will not work for me.

Comment: Its a 2D array rt? like array(0=>array('name' => 'saaaa', 'age' => 25));

Comment: my mistake, yes it is 2D array. However I want to maintain the value of the array between request. Just like a `SESSION` where that value is not changed when it is called over and over before it is destroyed. Appreciate your answer :-)